# Spring Security - Can´t use @Secured with the Role

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security

I have my User with the role from the table role. The table role has the roleId and the roleName.

```
1   ADMIN
```

Now i want to use @Secured in the backend.
I tried:

```
    @RequestMapping("/listShifts", method = [RequestMethod.GET])
    @Secured("ADMIN")
    fun listShifts(model: Model, @RequestParam(required = false) search: String?, employeeId: Int?, departmentId: Int?): String {
        return "listShifts"
    }
```

But I don´t get access to the site.

How can I fix this?

The user Entity looks like:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = [UniqueConstraint(name = "EMailAddress_UK", columnNames = ["EMailAddress"])])
class Employee(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var employeeId: Int? = null,
        @ManyToOne
        var role: Role? = Role(3),

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable @Secured annotation in your Spring Boot application you will need to first enable the Global Method Security by adding the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation to any Class in your application which has the @Configuration annotation or is a configuration class itself

Checkout this link for more info:

https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/spring-security-secured-annotation-example/#:~:text=To%20enable%20%40Secured%20annotation%20in,is%20a%20configuration%20class%20itself.